# Toggle class on generated toggle element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where I get a bit stuck and where I need some help. Let me explain myself by some code. I have the following HTML setup:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"></button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav" tabindex="-1">
         <div class="menuitem_wrapper" tabindex="-1">
              <a href="#" class="">Menu 1</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1">
                  <a href="#">Sub 1.1</a>
                  <a href="#">Sub 1.2</a>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="menuitem_wrapper" tabindex="-1">
              <a href="#" class="">Menu 2</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="-1">
                  <a href="#">Sub 2.1</a>
                  <a href="#">Sub 2.2</a>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have build in some functionality with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".collapsed").click(function() {
        $(".navbar-collapse").toggleClass('show-menu'); 
        $(".menuitem_wrapper").removeClass('menuitem_wrapper').addClass('menuitem_wrapper_mobile');
    });

    $(".menuitem_wrapper").click(function() {           
        $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").removeClass('dropdown-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu-mobile');       
    });

});
```

The functionality triggers whenever toggle button is pressed the hyperlinks: menu 1 and menu 2 are shown (the sub items are hidden via CSS).

The first part which I do not fully understand is why this works:

```
$(".menuitem_wrapper").click(function() {           
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").removeClass('dropdown-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu-mobile');       
});
```

and why this not:

```
$(".menuitem_wrapper_mobile").click(function() {            
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").removeClass('dropdown-menu').addClass('dropdown-menu-mobile');       
});
```

But the main problem that I have is whenever I press on the hyperlink: menu 1 or menu 2 the submenu is showed. But I want to create the functionality of having a toggle effect.

The hard part in creating this code is that I can not add any CSS classes manually to the divs. Because this menu is used in two ways. As a mobile menu which is presented to the user vertically and as a default menu which is presented horizontal with hover effects.

Can anyone help me  getting the desired effect, toggling, **without** having to add classes to my HTML code.

[JSFIDDLE OVER HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/k1pdagx1/)

Comment: Why not add and remove classes using javascript?

Comment: About your question: it happens because "menuitem_wrapper_mobile" class not on the DOM when the page is loading to bind to click event, so use $(document).on('click', '.class', function(){}) or move $(".menuitem_wrapper_mobile").click into $(".menuitem_wrapper").click function

Comment: @Rotan075 Is this the functionality you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/k1pdagx1/1/

Comment: You'll need to use deferred objects or promises since the class you're applying doesn't exist when the DOM is loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".collapsed").click(function() {
        $(".navbar-collapse").toggleClass('show-menu'); 
        $(".menuitem_wrapper").removeClass('menuitem_wrapper').addClass('menuitem_wrapper_mobile');
    });

    $(".menuitem_wrapper a:first-child").click(function() {         
        $(this).parent().children("div").toggleClass('dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mobile');     
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1pdagx1/2/)

Comment: Thank you. That s exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

instead of .removeclass or .addclass you can use .toggle or .toggleClass("active")

```
$( "" ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggle();
});

$("").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

you can add "slow" to the toggle function or some other transition so it can look like its having an smooth drop down instead of automatically showing the drop down menu. You should wrap your Menu1 and Menu 2 in li tags instead of a tags. The reason Menu 1 and Menu 2 don't have functionality its because you are not anywhere in your code giving it functionality to Menu and Menu 2, you are only wrapping it on a tags.